# Нажатие кнопки внутри строки вызывает так-же событие нажатия самой строки

Tags: javascript

Добрый день,
есть таблица и событие нажатия по строке. Так-же на строке есть кнопка "удалить".
Если я жму по строке-работает событие1, а если кнопку- работает событие нажатия кнопки и событие1, т.к. оно родительское.
Как убрать родительское событие1, когда нажата кнопка?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конце метода кнопки напишите return false или event.stopPropagation()

Суть: допустим есть у вас ссылка, и лежит она в div, когда вы кликаете по ссылке, то браузер ищет и вызывает обработчик клика у ссылки, div, document.body, т.к. в обратном порядке все они друг в друга входят, и как следствие - обработать клик может кто угодно (например обработчик клика может быть повешен не на кнопку, а на div и при вызове будет проверять - на какой дочерний элемент на самом деле был клик, это удобно при использовании динамического контента)

return false или event.stopPropagation() - отменяют такой
А event.preventDefault() - отменяют действие по умолчанию, например - переход по ссылке или сабмит формы

Comment: Спасибо.Разобрался. Ещё искал касательно ангуляра, если кому надо http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation  . И jquery http://www.wisdomweb.ru/editor/wweditor.php?fname=jqd_ispropstop